# Create link with specific owner/group

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create some symbolic links with a specific owner/group,
but it's always created with owner=root and group=root. Why?

This is my code:

```yaml
- name: Get the directories to create symbolic links
  find:
    paths: /myPath/
  register: result

- name: Creation of symbolic links 
  file:
    src: "{{ item.path }}" 
    dest: /Path_Dest/{{ item.path | basename }}
    owner: 'owner1'
    group: 'group1'
    state: link
  with_items: "{{ result.files }}"
```

Note :

- owner1 and group1 exist.
- No error in Ansible log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not specify `follow=False`, the symlink will be followed (because [default is follow=True](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-follow)) and the ownership and group will be applied to destination path. Use:

```yaml
- name: Creation of symbolic links 
  file:
    src: "{{ item.path }}" 
    dest: /Path_Dest/{{ item.path | basename }}
    owner: 'owner1'
    group: 'group1'
    state: link
    follow: False
  with_items: "{{ result.files }}"
```